# VSO Continuous Deployment Fails w/ Multiple Sites in Web Role

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-devops, azure-cloud-services

I have configured a cloud service to run multiple web applications in one web role. More information on this [is in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg433110.aspx).

The documentation does not appear to be correct for local builds with the Azure 2.3 SDK. Apparently, since SDK 1.8, the `physicalDirectory` attribute is not relative to the Azure cloud service project folder, but its output folder. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365254/did-azure-1-8-oct-2012-change-the-way-you-configure-multiple-sites-in-the-serv). By changing the path to `../../../Project.Name` the service can be built and deployed locally from VS2013 with SDK 2.3.

We also use continuous integration on Visual Studio Online. However, the project now fails to build with the message that the path to my second web project is invalid. The path it's trying to use is `C:\Project.Name\`. I don't think this is quite correct.

I have tested with `../Project.Name` as the `physicalDirectory` attribute value on VSO, but that also fails.

Is it a matter of somehow correctly configuring this for Visual Studio Online, or is it simply not currently supported?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find a way to do this? I found this http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c000812b-1118-4380-b80c-732b7b9f9ff2/issue-with-azuretfs-build-in-the-case-multiple-websites-in-single-webrole where a VSO employee states it is not currently possible but it was from last year:

Comment: Unfortunately not. I also posted this question on the VSO-TFS forum at MSDN, but no replies so far...

Comment: So if we all vote [here](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/5020886-support-deployment-of-multiple-websites-to-an-azur), maybe they'll add it in a future release. You'd think it shouldn't be such a big deal since it's supported in VS...

Comment: Yeah I added my vote. Something tells me it's got a long way to go before they consider implementing it.